# Getting unterminated string constant javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why am i getting "Unterminated string constant" java script error on below line

```
 lblWaiverMessage.innerText = hfState == "PR" ? 
'<%=HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/StartStopTime.ascx", 
"Label5_PRResource")%>'  : 
'<%=HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/StartStopTime.ascx", 
"Label5Resource1")%>' ;
```

below is the dynamic value of the above label

`lblWaiverMessage.innerText = hfState == 'PR' ?` 'I understand and agree that I may be scheduled to work more than eight `(8) hours` in a shift.
                                     If I work a shift of more than eight (8) hours, but not more than `10 hours` I agree that it is for the mutual benefit of me and the Company, and 
                                     I voluntarily consent to waive my 2nd required meal period of a shift only when my work and/or scheduled shift will be completed in `10 hours.`
                                     I voluntarily consent to the aforementioned statement for weekending'  : '' ;

Comment: Because you have a `newline` in the middle of a string!

Comment: data comes from a value in a resource file how do i handle this scenario ?

Comment: Remove all newlines in your string before the condition.